# Create a new column in spark data frame based on current Dataframe as a counter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

(Edited the DF's to make question more clear) Using Spark 2.2.0

I am new to spark and Scala programming and I have tried to look at questions posted before. All seem to answer in bits and pieces to what I am looking for but still does not address my problem. any help is greatly appreciated

I have a DataFrame that looks like below.

```
+------------------+--------------------+
|max(trip_audit_id)|max(trip_seq_end_no)|
+------------------+--------------------+
|                 1|                  23|
+------------------+--------------------+
```

I have another DF like below

```
+---------+---------+------+-------------------+
|CompanyId|VehicleId| Event|          date_time|
+---------+---------+------+-------------------+
|       83|   177010|   100|2017-08-03 2:00 AM|
|       83|   177010|800000|2017-08-03 2:30 AM|
|       83|   177010|   100|2017-08-03 3:00 AM|
|       84|   345678|   100|2017-08-03 3:20 AM|
|       84|   345678|800000|2017-08-03 4:00 AM|
|       83|   177010|800000|2017-08-03 9:00 AM|
|       83|   177010|   100|2017-08-04 2:00 AM|
|       83|   177666|800000|2017-08-04 2:30 AM|
+---------+---------+------+-------------------+
```

I need to take the first dataframe's `max(trip_seq_end_no)` and create a new column in my second DF as the running sequence number. In addition I need to put the datetime stamp of event = 800000 in the same line as event = 100. So My resulting Dataframe should ideally look like this.

```
+---------+---------+-----+-------------------+-----+-------------------+
|CompanyId|VehicleId|Event|      100_date_time|SeqID|   800000_date_time|
+---------+---------+-----+-------------------+-----+-------------------+
|       83|   177010|  100|2017-08-03 2:00 AM|    24| 2017-08-03 2:30 AM|
|       83|   177010|  100|2017-08-03 3:00 AM|    25| 2017-08-03 9:00 AM|
|       84|   345678|  100|2017-08-03 3:20 AM|    26| 2017-08-03 4:00 AM|
|       83|   177010|  100|2017-08-04 2:00 AM|    27| Null              |
|       83|   177666|  100|           NULL   |    28| 2017-08-04 2:30 AM|
+---------+---------+-----+-------------------+-----+-------------------+
```

Please help.

Thank you,

Comment: How do you match records with `Event == 8000000` to the right records with `Event = 100` - by **order**? by `date_time`? And what if two matching records have different `CompanyId` or `VehicleId` - should the solution ignore the values in the `8000000` records and use the ones in the `100` records?

Comment: Hi Tzach, Yes the ordering is on date_time and I do not care about the companyId or VehicleId, Its possible that I can have record for 800000 and no corresponding 100 event, in which case I can show the 100_date_time to be null.

Comment: Hi Tzach, Please see my edited comment here. Please ignore my above comment. Yes the ordering is on date_time and is associated with  companyId or VehicleId, however the sequence is on the event= 100 's date_time. Its possible that I can have record for 800000 and no corresponding 100 event, in which case I can show the 100_date_time can be null.

Comment: @Kask Could you edit your questions to show how the expected result will be like in the case your second DF has (84, 177010, 800000, "2017-08-03 07:08:38"), (85, 177010, 100, "2017-08-03 08:15:16")?

Comment: Hi saitejalakkimsetty, I have edited the post to reflect the DF i need. I am using spark 2,.2

Comment: Hi, I did some research and I know I can use lag and lead to pull the 800000 = date_time into next column. I am still having issues with the SeqID column. The solution I came up with is as follows

here 
seqNo = max(trip_seq_end_no)
dfEventsCnt = Max number if rows in second DF

val newDF = filteredDF.withColumn("Event_Type_hex1", when($"Event_Type_hex" === 100, lit(for(i<-seqNo+1 to dfEventsCnt) println(i))).otherwise(0))

Comment: I get a print of sequence numbers from 24 printed in new lines and ends with an error as follows

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.runtime.BoxedUnit ()
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:77)
  at